# Why is $.datepicker(); not functioning, yet $.hide(); is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using twitter bootstrap (generated through less), jquery and jquery UI. Here are the main imports and script tags on the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/assets/less/bootstrap.less">
    <script src="/assets/less/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/images/favicon.png">
    <link type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/my.css" />

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>
   <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- remember <link> tag for the jqueryUI css-->
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  <!--Jquery for the invite button datepicker-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").hide();
        return false;
    });
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Note the last  tag, the one hiding the div. This page ends up being blank, as the main div gets hidden (not shown here). If, hoewver I replace that with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            $("div").hide();
            return false;
        });
        </script>
```

Then nothing happens - the divs do not get hidden. I've tried using Firebug, but it starts hanging when I try and inspect the script.

Is it possible that my imports are somehow conflicting?

Comment: Try reproducing the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: You might also want to see if there's a conflict over the `$` by replacing it with `jQuery`.

Comment: Do you have more than one `#datepicker` in your html?

Comment: @alFReDNSH how can I import all my dependendencies? I am storing them on my computer for the time being.

Comment: @Jason I doubt that is the conflict, as $.hide() works.

Comment: @Luke that is the only #datepicker.

Comment: When you're using the Firebug console, did you leave out the datepicker call in your code and then try adding it in the console? What happens then? Is that when it's hanging?

Comment: @HenryHenrinson You don't need to build you whole website on jsfiddle. Just as much as you need to reproduce the problem. And the ones that you listed here, are all hosted online.